# Lightning not hitting an object?

Tags: unity, particles

I was following this tutorial, but the lightning is not hitting the other object as the video shows.
[image]

```
    private LineRenderer lRend;
private Vector3[] points = new Vector3[5];

private readonly int point_Begin = 0;
private readonly int point_Middle_Left = 1;
private readonly int point_Center = 2;
private readonly int point_Middle_Right = 3;
private readonly int point_End = 4;

public Transform line;

private readonly float randomPosOffset = 0.3f;
private readonly float randomWithOffsetMax = 2f;
private readonly float randomWithOffsetMin = 1f;

private readonly WaitForSeconds customFrame = new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);

void Start () {
    lRend = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    StartCoroutine(Beam());
}

private IEnumerator Beam()
{
    yield return customFrame;
    points[point_Begin] = transform.position;
    points[point_End] = line.position;
    CalculateMiddle();
    lRend.SetPositions(points);
    lRend.SetWidth(RandomWidthOffset(), RandomWidthOffset());
    StartCoroutine(Beam());
}

private float RandomWidthOffset()
{
    return Random.Range(randomWithOffsetMin, randomWithOffsetMax);
}

private void CalculateMiddle()
{
    Vector3 center = GetMiddleWithRandomness(transform.position, line.position);

    points[point_Center] = center;
    points[point_Middle_Left] = GetMiddleWithRandomness(transform.position, center);
    points[point_Middle_Right] = GetMiddleWithRandomness(center, line.position);
}

private Vector3 GetMiddleWithRandomness (Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2)
{
    float x = (point1.x + point2.x) / point_Center;
    float finalX = Random.Range(x - randomPosOffset, x + randomPosOffset);
    float y = (point1.y + point2.y) / point_Center;
    float finalY = Random.Range(y - randomPosOffset, y + randomPosOffset); 

    return new Vector3(finalX, finalY, 0);
}
}
```

Everything is good except that the lightning is not hitting the other object. What am I missing?

Comment: Please include the code in the question post, we're lazy and don't like to click on links :P (And links tend to rot, making posts completely useless.)

Comment: Sorry for that . can you now answered my question ?

Comment: Thanks! No, sorry, I'm not familiar with Unity, but give it a bit of time, more users will read your question!